# How to expose API Connect API in Bluemix Catalog

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I'm not able to see the APIs I create in the API Connect in the Bluemix Catalog.

Using API Connect Service in Bluemix I have created a new Catalog "BluemixCatalog"

I have made the following configuration:

BluemixCatalog -> Settings -> Portal -> "User Registration and Invitation" -> User Registry. I have configured it to be SAML.

BluemixCatalog -> Developers -> "Add Bluemix Organization". I have used a bluemix user email as the owner.

The organization owner receives the mail and log in.

Now I create an API, a Product and Publish it to the new "Bluemix Organization" but the API does not appear in the Blumix Catalog of the Bluemix Organization owner.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The published APIs are visible in Explore APIs tab of APIs. Please see the included screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you. Full instructions in:

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/apic_006.html#apic_025

Now the APIs in bluemix are a link to the portal, it is not a "service" in the bluemix catalog, if I do not remember wrong in v4 the API was in the bluemix catalog and the suscription was done by Bluemix under the covers, now you have to do it manually from portal as any other API, what you have in bluemix about the API is just a link to the portal.